# Show the convergence or divergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to check the convergence of series $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(1+2\cos{\frac{\pi n}{4}})^n}{3^n\ln{n}}$

It seems, that this series is divergent, but i can't to show it.

$\dfrac{(1+2\cos{\frac{\pi n}{4}})^n}{3^n} = 1\space\space$for $\space n = 8k\space\space$ and we have series $\sum\dfrac{1}{\ln{n}}$, but it isn't positive series, so I don't know how to use this fact.

I spent a lot of time on this task and tried to use all convergence tests that I know, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Did you mean to set your bounds from $n=2$?

Comment: "I spent a lot of time on this task" Excellent. But you stayed stuck on the case $n=8k$? How comes you never got interested in $n=8k+1$, $n=8k+2$, etc.?

Comment: I fixed bounds. Of course i intrested in this cases, but all this series is convergent and case $n = 8k$ is unique. This series isn't positive so I can't do any permutations, can I?

Comment: But I think you are very close to the solution.  You have split the series into eight parts, seven are convergent and the eighth, $n=8k$, diverges ($\to\infty$).  The series must diverge.

Comment: @Malcolm, Doesn't Riemann series theorem contradict such actions?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem

Comment: But your sum is not conditionally convergent.  It can be written as absolutely convergent piece + diverging to infinity piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your series
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\,\dfrac{(1+2\cos{\frac{\pi n}{4}})^n}{3^n\ln{n}}
$$
diverges to infinity.  As you note, the case where $n=8k$ is important.  Indeed each of the sub-series
$$
\sum_{\substack{n\geq 2\\ n= 8k+a}} \dfrac{(1+2\cos{\frac{\pi n}{4}})^n}{3^n\ln{n}}
$$
for $a = 1,\ldots 7$ is absolutely convergent by comparision with $\sum \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)^{n}$.

Fix an $\epsilon>0$, for sufficiently large $N$,

$$
\sum_{n = 2}^{N}\dfrac{(1+2\cos{\frac{\pi n}{4}})^n}{3^n\ln{n}}
> L-\epsilon
+\sum_{\substack{n = 8k\\ n\leq N}}\frac{1}{\ln n}
$$

Where $L$ is the sum of the sub-series over $n\geq 2$, $n=8k+a$, $a = 1,\ldots,7$.

Now let $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Intuitively I understand this, but for this conclusion we need to use permutation, needn't we? In this way it contradicts Riemann theorem. Can you please explain, why we can use this inequality.

For example, $$\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n} = -\ln{2}$$, but we can't say that $$\sum\frac{(-1)^{\sigma{n}}}{\sigma{n}} > -\ln{2} - \epsilon$$ and in my case we have same situation, haven't we?

Comment: @НикитаСвербягин In your example, you could say that $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{n} > -\ln 2 - \epsilon$ for $N$ big enough.  That's what I've applied to the convergent sum where $n \neq 0 \pmod 8$

Comment: I understood, thank you!